# Storedprocedure to check the value already in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to insert values in to a table.Here I need to check the values for insert is already in the table .how can I check this in my stored procedure.here is my stored procedure.

```
USE [Databasse_sync]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_getyoutubevideo] 

    @ProductID nvarchar(200),
    @YoutubeUrl nvarchar(200),
    @YoutubeImage nvarchar(200)

AS

INSERT INTO YoutubeVideo(ProductID,YoutubeUrl,YoutubeImage,DATASET)VALUES(@ProductID,@YoutubeUrl,@YoutubeImage,'DAT')
RETURN
```

Here I need to check the ProducId is same or not?If ProductId is same then Update otherwise Insert.>>>??

Comment: @DarrenDavies EXITS is possible.but I need to check whether a ProductId having the same YoutubeUrl  then update the table otherwise Insert new valus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE [Databasse_sync]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_getyoutubevideo] 

    @ProductID nvarchar(200),
    @YoutubeUrl nvarchar(200),
    @YoutubeImage nvarchar(200)

AS

MERGE [YoutubeVideo] AS Y
        USING (SELECT @ProductID,@YoutubeUrl, @YoutubeImage) AS SourceRow (ProductID,YoutubeUrl,YoutubeImage)
        ON Y.[ProductID] = SourceRow.ProductID
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
                Y.[ProductID] = SourceRow.ProductID
                ,Y.[YoutubeUrl] = SourceRow.YoutubeUrl
                ,Y.[YoutubeImage] = SourceRow.YoutubeImage

        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (ProductID,YoutubeUrl, YoutubeImage, DATASET)
            VALUES (SourceRow.ProductID,SourceRow.YoutubeUrl, SourceRow.YoutubeImage,'DAT');
RETURN
```

Comment: @Arun..If you want to check the YoutubeURL also add the same in ON condition

Answer (score 1):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM YoutubeVideo WHERE ProductID=@ProductID) BEGIN
    --INSERT HERE
END
ELSE BEGIN
    --UPDATE HERE
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  DECLARE @EXISTS BIT

  SELECT @EXISTS = 1 
  WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT ID FROM YouTubeVideo
         WHERE ID = @ProductID 
         AND YoutubeUrl = @YoutubeUrl)

  IF @Exists = 1
  BEGIN
    -- Update
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    -- INSERT
  END
```

Comment: uh, in order for this to be concurrent-safe, the system will need to lock the entire table (from writes, at least).  You should probably point that out in your answer, in case that's an important performance consideration.

Answer (score 1):

@Arun

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_getyoutubevideo] 

    @ProductID nvarchar(200),
    @YoutubeUrl nvarchar(200),
    @YoutubeImage nvarchar(200)

 AS
  BEGIN
     DECLARE @counter INT

     @counter=SELECT COUNT(ProductID) FROM YoutubeVideo WHERE ProductID=@ProductID

     IF(@counter = 0)
     BEGIN
         INSERT INTO YoutubeVideo(ProductID,YoutubeUrl,YoutubeImage,DATASET)VALUES(@ProductID,@YoutubeUrl,@YoutubeImage,'DAT')  
     END

END
```

if u want to check record is inserted or not then u can take one out parameter and chek recored is inserted or not.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_getyoutubevideo] 

@ProductID nvarchar(200),
@YoutubeUrl nvarchar(200),
@YoutubeImage nvarchar(200)
```

`AS BEGIN`

```
 DECLARE @counter int 


 @counter = SELECT count(ProductID) FROM YoutubeVideo WHERE ProductID=@ProductID

 IF(@counter = 0)
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO YoutubeVideo(ProductID,YoutubeUrl,YoutubeImage,DATASET)VALUES(@ProductID,@YoutubeUrl,@YoutubeImage,'DAT') 
     End

 ELSE
 begin
 UPDATE SET 
            ProductID = @ProductID
            ,YoutubeUrl = @YoutubeUrl
            ,YoutubeImage = @YoutubeImage 
 END      END
```